# Date Difference from Log table

Tags: mysql

Hello guys I need help with this function, I'm using MySQL database server
version: 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu).

I want to be able to get how many "weeks" it took a worker to get hired. i have a table that stores log data whenever the worker's status change.

```
logid   workerid   statusid       timestamp
1000    10         1(available)   2016-04-10
1001    10         2(Hired)       2016-04-24
```

what i want to have is :
It took worker 10 two weeks to get hired.

I already looked at `DATEDIFF(first date, second date)` function but I have to use two different `where` conditions for each date, I have no idea how to do this?

Comment: so you need datediff between status 1 and 2 per workerid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join same table and to use `DATEDIFF()`:

```
SELECT
    e1.workerid,
    DATEDIFF(e2.`timestamp`, e1.`timestamp`) daysDiff,
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(e2.`timestamp`, e1.`timestamp`) / 7, 0) weeksDiff
FROM
    employees e1
    INNER JOIN employees e2 ON e1.workerid = e2.workerid
WHERE
    e1.statusid = 1
    AND e2.statusid = 2
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
| workerid | daysDiff | weeksDiff |
+----------+----------+-----------+
|       10 |       14 |         2 |
+----------+----------+-----------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: Thank you a lot my man, this is perfectly works. i will try to understand how this inner join works.

Comment: Great! Mark the answer in order to close the topic.

Comment: how this `INNER JOIN` will be done if i need to link more tables keys links  to the where conditions. should i add more `INNER JOIN` statement or should i just add them in the `where` clause?

Comment: If you have more tables you need to join them, otherwhise (if the table is the same), you should add them in WHERE clause.